# ошибочно изменил приложения для открытья файла , помогите как исправить , изначально полмолчанию ничего не было

Tags: windows, файлы

[image: файл приложение открывает браузер]

я по ошибке открыл файл приложения с помощью internet explorer , теперь из-за этого большинство приложений возникают ошибки или же открывают браузер с собой

Answer (score 0):

Ничего страшного не случилось. Все можно починить правой кнопкой из проводника.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А далее выбрать какую-нибудь программу, умеющую показывать md-файлы. Они текстовые, поэтому можно выбрать блокнот, ну или какой-нибудь редактор этого формата.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]